# How to test module when it needs Application.class and one is ine the other module?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have multi-modules gradle project which has follows structure:

```
Module-A
    main
        java
            com.example.project.main
                Application.class
Module-B
    main
        java
            com.example.project.other
                SomeController.class
    test
        java
            com.example.project.other
                SomeControllerTest.class
```

I want to test the class `SomeController` within the test `SomeControllerTest`. `SomeControllerTest` demands real application context with some replaced classes. How i can get `Application`'s functional for `SomeControllerTest` configuring?